# Resource folder for different text sizes

Tags: android, user-interface, resources, font-size

I'm developing and Android application that will support changes in the size of its text when the user changes it on settings.
For this reason I want to know if there's a way for me to separate my application resources according to the font size changes. For example, can I create an resource folder named like "drawable-huge" (the font size). If so do you know the suffixes I can use it on the folders? If that isn't possible, do you know any other thing I can do to prevent UI problems when the font sizes are bigger or smaller?

Thank you.

Comment: Nope, that is not a supported alternative resource name, so it won't work AFAIK. This will have to be done programmatically.

Comment: Do you think I could use onConfigurationChanged to set specific drawables?

Comment: I'm not sure since I'm not really sure of what you intent to do here. In fact I don't get the point of doing what you are trying to do. `sp` sized texts are different in pixels depending on the screen/device...

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 65);
```

which 65 is the font size in sp

for more information vist http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize%28int,%20float%29